# Angular 2: blur contenteditable div on enter

Tags: javascript, html, angular, blur

I have a contenteditable div that looks like this:

```
 <div class="wall-title col-sm-12" 
        [attr.contenteditable]="wall.title && wall.title !== 'Favorites'" 
        (blur)="wallNameChanged($event.target.outerText)"
        (keyup.enter)="wallNameChanged($event.target.outerText)">
           {{wall.title}}
 </div>
```

When the user presses enter after editing the div content, I want to blur the div. Currently, a new line character is getting added and a new line is visible in the UI.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to **prevent** the default operation: ( which in this case is to add new line )

```
wallNameChanged($event) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.target.blur();
  // remove extra lines
  let text = $event.target.outerText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
  // do whatever you need with the text
}

<div (keyup.enter)="wallNameChanged($event)">
   {{wall.title}}
</div>
```

Comment: This certainly helped. The div is getting blurred.
However, the extra line is still visible in the UI, as a result of enter. How can hide that extra line?

Comment: You can use simple string replace for example: text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ");

Comment: FunStuff, the string replacement won't work because the data is bound to the div element using interpolation. And the user input on div did not affect the model wall.title. This is what the UI element looks like after enter and blur.

Comment: wall.title = text ?

Comment: Tried that. Didn't help. The new line character stays.

Continuing from my previous comment:
<div class="wall-title col-sm-12" contenteditable="true">
            abcd 123<div><br></div></div>

Notice how 'abcd 123' has appeared in the next line? There is a new line character there.

Comment: You can create new pipe that will simple do this:
{{wall.title | removeBreaks}}
this is the best solution

Comment: It it's works for you let me know and I will add the pipe to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I do this which seems to work.

```
<div contenteditable="true" (keydown.enter)="onEnter($event)" />
```

Then in typescript:

```
  onEnter($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    this.sendMessage();
  }
```

Comment: Yep this works :) --- notice: we need to use `keydown` instead `keyup` if we want preventDefault to take effect

Answer (score 1):

in your component :

```js
onEnter($event){
  $event.target.blur()
  $event.preventDefault()
  this.wallNameChanged($event.target.outerText)
}
```

in your template :

```html
<div class="wall-title col-sm-12" 
             [attr.contenteditable]="wall.title && wall.title !== 'Favorites'" 
             (blur)="wallNameChanged($event.target.outerText)"
             (keyup.enter)="onEnter($event)">
            {{wall.title}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by temporarily change value of you model `wall.title` (by adding space at the end and remove it after 0ms :P ) which force angular to refresh div DOM element:

So change template to this:

```
<div class="wall-title col-sm-12"      
     [attr.contenteditable]="wall.title && wall.title !== 'Favorites'"                           
     [textContent]="wall.title"
     (input)="wall.title=$event.target.textContent"                                
     (keyup.enter)="wallNameChanged($event)"
     (blur)="wallNameChanged($event)"
></div>
```

And in component code:

```
public finishEditTeamName(event) 
{    
    event.target.blur();
    let str = this.wall.title;
    this.wall.title = str + ' ';
    setTimeout( () => {
        this.wall.title = str;
    }, 0);
}
```